# All apps crashed with the message 'The application ABC can't be opened'. Event Terminal cannot create process

Tags: macos, crash

All apps crashed with the message 'The application ABC can't be opened'. Event Terminal cannot create process

It happens after hours of working. 
My current temp solution is Restart.
[image: terminal]
[image: error message]

My record when the error happens
https://vimeo.com/396136699

Comment: No-one is going to click through to some random GDrive link. What's it supposed to be?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I record the screen when the error happen. Let me update the description

Comment: @Tetsujin updated. Please help

Comment: 1. Run Disk First Aid from Recovery 2a, if the drive is OK,Install Malwarebytes & run. 2b, if it isn't, repair the OS install from recovery.